# Build Boost 1.75: Compiler GNU-4.8.1.10

Tags: boost, gnu, vxworks

I try to build the Boost library V1.75 with the GNU Compiler V4.8.1.10 which is part of VxWork7 baseline SR0540.

My questions are:

- which export variables has to be set, to point on the right Gnu compiler?
- which options or flags has to be set to bootstrap.sh or bootstrap.bat ?
- which options or flags has to be set to b2.exe ?

Thx in advance

Answer (score 1):

From the command line build, make sure that the environment variables has been set.

Open a DOS Command (Windows) or Terminal (Linux), go to the installation directory
and execute the command

```
wrenv.exe -p vxworks-7
```

or

```
./wrenv.sh -p vxworks-7
```

Then the build shall take the correct compiler provided with the installation.

When creating a project from Workbench, the build environement is set automatically when starting the IDE.

Comment: Thx for fast response: 
After setup the environment variables, I suppose before to call the b2.exe, the bootstrap.bat with the gcc option as toolset, should be called?

Comment: The steps described here should help: https://harmonicss.co.uk/vxworks/adding-vxworks-7-boost-c-library-support/

Comment: Once built you can take the following tutorial: https://harmonicss.co.uk/vxworks/building-and-running-vxworks-7-boost-c-applications/

Comment: I have also found thees sides.
The different is that Wind River VxWorks 7, SR0620 has a Boost build configuration.
VxWorks 7, SR0540 Boost has to build separately with b2.exe and bootstrap.bat

Comment: Seems that before using b2 command the source build shall be build once extracting boost to the app directory (https://github.com/lijie-jiang/vxworks7-layer-for-boost)

Comment: This solution (github.com/lijie-jiang/vxworks7-layer-for-boost) works with one drawback. I was not able to update boost from V1.59 to V1.74.